# How to send data in base.html.twig in symfony 4?

Tags: php, orm, twig, symfony4

All files extend `base.html.twig` in my Symfony (v4.4) project.

I would like to know, how to send data in `base.html.twig`, because it doesn't have a route.

That would allow me to send categories (title) to the nav bar.

How can I do it?

Comment: Unclear, any data send from the controller to a template which extends `base.html.twig` will be available in the base template

Answer (score 0):

You should create blocks on the extended template, which can be replaced on "child" templates. You can learn more [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/extends.html).

After that, you can send data on a "bag", that will be used (inside these blocks) by the template your controller are using.

On your case, you can also create something like:

```html
<nav>
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
// Other stuff
</nav>
```

and pass the value of "title" in the bag for the child templates.
Or set it in the template with the `{% set title = "Title 1" %}`. You can learn more about the "set" [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/set.html)